# How to subscribe channel with user presence in pubnub with swift?

Tags: ios, swift, pubnub

I am using pubnub SDk for socket stuffs. pubnub provides a feature to know the online/offline users with it's method hereNow. But it's not getting called when the user gets online or goes offline as this should be involked like socket listener. If anybody has some idea about this please help me out.

```
func registerForConnectRoom(roomId: String) {
    pubnub.subscribe(to: ["ch:callroom:" + roomId], withPresence: true)
   let listener = SubscriptionListener()
    
   listener.didReceiveSubscription = { event in
     switch event {
     case let .messageReceived(message):
       print("heuuu \(message)")
     
       case let .connectionStatusChanged(status):
         print("Status Received: \(status)")
       case let .presenceChanged(presence):
         print("Presence Received: \(presence)")
       case let .subscribeError(error):
         print("Subscription Error \(error)")
       default:
         break
        }
   }
}

func hereNow(roomId: String) {
    pubnub.hereNow(on: ["ch:callroom:" + roomId], includeState: true) { result in
        
      switch result {
      case let .success(presenceByChannel):
        print("Total channels \(presenceByChannel.totalChannels)")
        print("Total occupancy across all channels \(presenceByChannel.totalOccupancy)")
        if let myChannelPresence = presenceByChannel["ch:callroom:" + roomId] {
          print("The occupancy for `my_channel` is \(myChannelPresence.occupancy)")
          print("The list of occupants for `my_channel` are \(myChannelPresence.occupants)")
        }
      case let .failure(error):
        print("Failed hereNow Response: \(error.localizedDescription)")
      }
    }
}
```

calling these methods in viewDidLoad

Comment: Please provide full code so we can see how you are calling them, please.

Comment: I can see you updated your code (a little) but we really need to see how you're calling this from viewDidLoad. And if you can enable SDK logging and reproduce and share the logs (with PN support - support@pubnub.com and a link to this SO post), we can get to the bottom of this faster. PN has free support and it is fast.

Comment: I saw your newer post that is similar to this one. Did you figure this issue out yet? If so, please add "Your Answer" below so we know you are done with this one. Let me know if I can assist.

Comment: Yes I have resolved the issue and the issue is when we configure pubnub then there is an optional uuid parameter which I was missing. If you don't send this parameter then we can't figure out user presence.

Comment: that is true but if you do not set UUID then PN SDK will auto-generate one for you. You should answer your own post as it will give you more SO points.